# Does Antimagic Field block line of effect for spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, antimagic-field, line-of-effect

Consider a 100 foot long, 10 foot wide corridor. The middle 10 feet of the corridor are under the effects of [Antimagic Field](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field/). A wizard at one end of the corridor wants to cast, say, [Blindness/Deafness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blindness-deafness/) on a troll at the other end of the corridor (note that neither is within the field).

Does the Antimagic Field block line of effect for the spell, or does the spell's effect travel up to the field, be suppressed as it instantaneously "passes through" the field, and then resume beyond the field to affect the troll?

Comment: Related thread: http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?312558-Casting-spells-in-Antimagic-Fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you are only reading the spell. There are more rules for [antimagic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Antimagic) under the general magic rules. Which honestly the spell should mention. Not even the site links to these rules.

In your case, what happens is that the spell has no issues traveling through the field, it just cant (for lack of better word) manafest inside the area. This falls under rule 3

> Spell areas that include both an antimagic area and a normal area, but are not centered in the antimagic area, still function in the normal area. If the spell’s center is in the antimagic area, then the spell is suppressed.

Due to the comment, I will explain in greater detail.

A caster who stands outside the field can cast a spell and have it travel into and out of the field and have it take effect with no side effects from the field. Its only when the spell is cast into the field (or cast in the field) that its prevented from working.

To further this I will quote something from the spell itself from the end of the first paragraph.

> **it prevents the functioning of any magic items or spells within its confines**

You can further look at the part about what happens with summoned creatures

> Summoned creatures of any type wink out if they enter an antimagic field. They reappear in the same spot once the field goes away.

Comment: I'm not asking about an area spell, I'm asking about a single target spell in a situation in which any line of effect for the spell must pass through the field.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I have updated my answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Since the antimagic field is invisible, it doesnt block line of sight, and since it says nothing about blocking line of effect in the spell, the short answer is No, antimagic field does not block line of effect.

> An antimagic field suppresses any spell or magical effect used within, brought into, or cast into the area, **but does not dispel it**.

Spells can pass right through, but as long as they do not take affect inside the antimagic field they will still work. Another way to think about it is  a buff like mage armor, you can walk into the field and lose the AC bonus. But as soon as you walk out the other end you gain it back because it was never dispelled. Now imagine the same thing but instead of you its a fireball being cast through, if it detonates inside the field, nothing happens. But if it passes through and detonates on the other side it still deals damage, but not to anyone still in the field because the field suppresses that part of the explosion. Also, Blindness/Deafness isn't a missile, so it never really passes though the antimagic field anyway.